# PHP Session won't save unique value

Tags: php

I want to save the `name=""` part of this button

```
<button type="submit" class="btn grey large" id="taxicompany" name="<? echo $rows['company']; ?>">select</button>
```

So when i do this

```
<?php echo "".$_SESSION['POSTDATA']['taxicompany'].''; ?>
```

it displays the value of `name=""`

But it won't display?

Comment: you want to save taxi name in session?

Comment: I would like to save the name= part of the button? So the $company bit?

Comment: Their are 5 choices and each one has a unique name tag on the button. So i would like to save the name tag of the button so the session knows which one they picked?

Comment: and your button is the part of your form?

Comment: if there is no form than you need to use AJAX

Comment: Sorry yes their is a form

Comment: Form, Method is POST and action leads to another page

Comment: alright, than check my answer, i hope this will help you

Comment: You aren't taking the post var, which is in `$_POST`, and storing it in `$_SESSION` to begin with, anywhere in this code.  You need something like `$_SESSION['taxicompany'] = $_POST['name']` in your code, somewhere.

Comment: Yes i did, I did not post it that was a mistake on my behalf. This has been answered now. Thanks for the replies

Answer (score 4):

Why do you not give the button a value

```
<button type="submit" class="btn grey large" id="taxicompany" name="taxicompany" value="<? echo $rows['company']; ?>">select</button>
```

Then when you submit your form and reference $_POST['taxicompany'] you will have the value

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_value.asp

Comment: Thank you, That has worked. How do i close this question as answered?

Comment: @PHPMono Click the green tick next to the question you'd like to accept as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<form method="post">
<button type="submit" class="btn grey large" id="taxicompany" name="taxicompany" value="your company name">select</button>
</form>

// PHP code
if(isset($_POST['taxicompany']))
{
    $_SESSION['POSTDATA']['taxicompany'] = $_POST['taxicompany'];
    echo $_SESSION['POSTDATA']['taxicompany']; //your company name
}
```